# Canvas starts lagging after time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My game in canvas after some minuts after running starts lagging. I have no idea where is the problem. The code has 200 lines, so I decides attach the link to github, instead of writing code here. I will be grateful for any suggestions. Many thanks! 
https://github.com/Ryczko/four-simple-JS-games/blob/master/scripts/heart.js

Comment: All those setTimeout / setIntervals, especially ones inside recursive functions are likely the source of the issue. I recommend using a single animation loop, using requestAnimationFrame, instead of using setIntervals.

Comment: I tried your game, I played during about 1 minute and the performances didn't decrease. However I agree with @George, you should use a single update/animation loop, better design and better performances.